# What is the best way to save permanent data in one class and be able retrieve it in another class

Tags: ios

I would like to save this array of dictionaries and be able to retrieve it another class and make decisions based upon it.

this is the array:

```
NSArray* cellInfoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[manufacturerTextField text],[lotNumberTextField text],[expirationDateTextField text],[techniqueTextField text],[cellNumberTextField text],[rhhrProfileTextField text],[donorNumberTextField text], nil];
    NSArray* keyNamingArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"company",@"lot",@"expDate",@"tech",@"whichCell",@"rhTyping",@"donor", nil];

NSArray* resultsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[capitalDResultLabel text],[capitalCResultLabel text],[capitalEResultLabel text],[cResultLabel text],[eResultLabel text],[fStarResultLabel text],[cwResultLabel text],[vResultLabel text],[capitalKResultLabel text],[kResultLabel text],[kpaResultLabel text],[kpbResultLabel text],[jsaResultLabel text],[jsbResultLabel text],[fyaResultLabel text],[fybResultLabel text],[jkaResultLabel text],[jkbResultLabel text],[xgaResultLabel text],[leaResultLabel text],[lebResultLabel text],[capitalSResultLabel text],[sResultLabel text],[mResultLabel text],[nResultLabel text],[p1ResultLabel text],[luaResultLabel text],[lubResultLabel text], nil];

NSArray* antigenNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"D",@"C",@"E",@"c",@"e",@"f*",@"Cw",@"V",@"K",@"k",@"Kpa",@"Kpb",@"Jsa",@"Jsb",@"Fya",@"Fyb",@"Jka",@"Jkb",@"Xga",@"Lea",@"Leb",@"S",@"s",@"M",@"N",@"P1",@"Lua",@"Lub", nil];

_cellInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:cellInfoArray forKeys:keyNamingArray];
_resultDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:resultsArray forKeys:antigenNames];

finalCellOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_cellInfo,@"clerk",_resultDictionary,@"theResults", nil];
```

this is probably something basic, but i have been trying several things (archiver, property list, nsuserdefaults) and i keep getting "null".

the user should be able to modify the data; thus, if we use a filepath, the second class should know that too.

i dont necessarily need any code from you guys; if i get some guidance on where to focus my research to be able to do this, it would be appreciated.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a case where a singleton class would be of use to you.  Application-wide access to the data and serialization/deserialization would be handled by your singleton.

```
@interface ApplicationData : NSObject

+ (id)sharedData;

//  your class properties that expose the data

@end

@implementation ApplicationData

+ (id)sharedData {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ApplicationData *cSharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ cSharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return cSharedInstance;
}

// you'll need to provide for serialization/deserialization as you are doing now.

@end
```

Thereafter, your access to the shared data is via: `[[ApplicationData sharedData] cellInfoArray]` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response NSBum; That's a really good tool to know about; I wonder if the data would persist between launches. since I posted this I started experiencing with core data and it seems to be the way to go.Thanks again, I really appreciate the response and learned something new from it

Comment: Core Data is often the right way to go for data persistence.  Like all things, it depends; and it comes with its own share of complexities to deal with.  I usually use Core Data for the model layer of the applications.  To answer your question, though, a singleton class by itself would not solve the problem of persistence between launches, which is why I comment on the need for a serialization/deserialization scheme, too.